# Getting thumbnails to all be the same size if images are of unknown size

Tags: php

I am currently trying to create a gallery page for a client. I don't want the client to have to change any code so I am trying to make my gallery import all images from a folder and display them all as thumbnails that are the same size.

I've been able to fetch/display all the images properly and open up the lightbox, my problem is a lot of the thumbnails don't work properly. I'm trying to scale the image down while maintaining the aspect ratio and just cutting off the excess image. It seems that if the image is smaller than the size I set for the thumbnail it works properly, but if it's larger it just seems to scale the image down to the correct width. Here is an image to show what I mean:

[image]

I'm really not sure where to go from here.

I would preferably like to keep the aspect ratio

This is my make thumbs function:

```
function make_thumb($src,$dest,$desired_width, $desired_height, $ext) {
  $size=480;
  /* read the source image */
  if($ext == 'jpg' || $ext = 'jpeg') {
          $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
  }
  if($ext == 'png') {
          $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($src);
  }
  $width = imagesx($source_image);
  $height = imagesy($source_image);

  $ratio = $width / $height;

  $targetWidth = $targetHeight = min($size, max($width, $height));

  if ($ratio < 1) {
      $targetWidth = $targetHeight * $ratio;
  } else {
      $targetHeight = $targetWidth / $ratio;
  }

  $srcWidth = $width;
  $srcHeight = $height;
  $srcX = $srcY = 0;

  $targetWidth = $targetHeight = min($width, $height, $size);

  if ($ratio < 1) {
      $srcX = 0;
      $srcY = ($height / 2) - ($width / 2);
      $srcWidth = $srcHeight = $width;
  } else {
      $srcY = 0;
      $srcX = ($width / 2) - ($height / 2);
      $srcWidth = $srcHeight = $height;
  }


  /* create a new, "virtual" image */
  $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth,$targetHeight);
  /* copy source image at a resized size */
  imagecopyresized($virtual_image,$source_image,0,0,$srcX,$srcY,$targetWidth,$targetHeight,$srcWidth,$srcHeight);
  /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
  if($ext == 'jpg' || $ext = 'jpeg') {
          imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dest);
  }
  if($ext == 'png') {
          imagepng($virtual_image,$dest);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not you use `add_image_size('name', width, height, true)`

Comment: I was under the impression that add_images_size() is wordpress only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issues.

First, I had $ext = 'jpeg' instead of ==

Second I had to change:

```
if ($ratio < 1) {
  $targetWidth = $targetHeight * $ratio;
} else {
  $targetHeight = $targetWidth / $ratio;
}
```

to

```
if ($ratio < 1) {
  $targetWidth = $targetHeight / $ratio;
} else {
  $targetHeight = $targetWidth / $ratio;
}
```